# Excel Replace all found chars

Tags: excel, interop

I've been trying to replace all "#" in a Excel worksheet using a winform application...

I tried with something like this

```
Excel.WorksheetClass excelWorksheet = (Excel.WorksheetClass)application.Worksheets[1];
        excelWorksheet.Cells.Replace(@"\", "", Excel.XlLookAt.xlWhole, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, false, Type.Missing, false, false);
```

But it just replace those "#" that are alone in a cell, if the cell value is "#ABC" then it does not replaces, advanced option in excel allow to do this, but how can I do that using Iterop classes.

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The third parameter `XlLookAt` is the problem. You need to use `xlPart` for a search which will match only part of the cell.

Comment: Hey thanks!

I was getting mad with this one, I thought that parameter indicates a range or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

darsahan.

Here's the code I used.

```
class ExcelOpener
{
    public static void OpenTxtInExcel(string name, string filename)
    {
        Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        application.Visible = true;
        application.Workbooks.OpenText
        (
            filename,
            missing,
            1,
            Excel.XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
            Excel.XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
            missing,
            missing,
            missing,
            missing, 
            missing,
            true, //True, using a custom delimiter
            @"#", //This is the custom delimiter
            missing,
            missing,
            missing,
            missing,
            missing,
            missing
        );

        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)application.Worksheets[1];
        excelWorksheet.Cells.Replace(@"\", "", Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, false, Type.Missing, false, false); 


    }
}
```

Regards